# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After i upgrade the EntityFramework to  `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />`

I start getting erros like:

> - System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
> - System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The
>     connection's current state is open.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and
>   available Connection. The connection's current state is open.] at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method)

I've two versions, one with previous EF version and gives NO ERROR and a new one with the new version wich gives this erros.

Anyone knows whats is?

PS: I use Newrelic to monitor the application

Comment: This error message is typical to multithread operations on same context

Comment: I've no function with multithread operations.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @Alireza what kind of code? I can't reproduce the error in my machine neither on my homolog environment. This only happens in production environment. And i've already create a new machine and the problem continuous.

Comment: Having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Seems, you have to follow the instructions from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51e097dd-ae19-4cd6-85af-18b002272226/ef4-entityexception-the-connections-current-state-is-connecting?forum=adodotnetentityframework):

> For anyone still having this problem, look check this link:
>
> [How to: Manually Open the Connection from the Object Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738698.aspx)
>
> The problem is the entity framework automatically opens and closes a
>   connection with each call to the database, thus when using a
>   transaction, you are attempting to spread a transaction out over
>   multiple connections which elevates to MSDTC.
>
> Open the connection manually and close it when you are done. Then the
>   framework will use only one connection for all your calls.
>
> Again, check the link for the details.